# How to find the Transaction ID from the Payment Id?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using `/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-xxxxxxx/execute` to execute a payment. I could not find the Transaction ID in the response from this API call.

By PAYID-xxxxxx I mean the id that is returned from creating a payment at `/v1/payments/payment`.

By Transaction ID, I mean the term used in the facilitator's payment activity details, which in my case is a 17-digit number. In this view, there is no reference to Payment Id. As a result, I am unable to connect the payment made on my web page to the transaction in the activity record.

How do I link up the Payment Id and the Transaction ID?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction ID is there in the response **transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id**.You can verify this id is present in activity details page.

```
{
"id": "PAYID-LR3XGPI5DV72242AN531734A",
 --
 ---
"transactions": [
    {
      "related_resources": [
            {
                "sale": {
                    "id": "9A243273UY3345417",
                     ---
                     ---
            } ]
    } }
```